# bookdown Error 'CTeX fontset `mac' is unavailable in current mode.' when using output format pdf_book & pdf_document2

Tags: r, bookdown, tinytex

I'm using 'bookdown' with `RStudio`, `tinyTex` and `pandoc` to write a report in Chinese. Because I need to use cross reference, I have to set the output format to 'pdf_document2', but I have an issue with `CTeX fontest`.

First, here is the YAML part:

```
---
title: "title"
author:
  - author
documentclass: ctexart
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2
bibliography: bib_v1.bib
csl: chinese-author-date.csl
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
classoption: "hyperref,"
---
```

And there is something wrong when I build the book, which says

> 'CTeX fontset `mac' is unavailable in current mode.'

Here's the whole error info:

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/mac'
TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you are interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read     http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
! Critical ctex error: "fontset-unavailable"
! 
! CTeX fontset 'mac' is unavailable in current mode.
! 
! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! 
! CTeX fontset 'mac' is unavailable in current mode.
! 
! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! CTeX fontset 'mac' is unavailable in current mode.
! 
! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! 
! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

Error: Failed to compile _main.tex. See _main.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains mac
Please delete _main.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I'm not familiar with LaTeX, and don't know how to fix the issue. I've tried to build the [bookdown-Chinese demo](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese) here, and it succeeded. I also tried to use the template of this demo in my own file, or use the output format `pdf_book`, but I still had the same problem.

So is there something I can do to fix it?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's an old question, I want to supply the answer I found that may help others. For Chinese documents, we should install the package `rticles`, and do the following in the .rmd file header.

```
---
documentclass: ctexart
output: 
    rticles::ctex
---
```

Answer (score 2):

The bookdown-chinese demo uses XeLaTeX: https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/_output.yml#L22 You could do the same like this:

```
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```