# How to change to another bibliography style in Bookdown

Tags: r, markdown, bookdown

I want to another bibliography style instead of apalike in Bookdown, and when I changed to nature which is number style, and built the book, it prompted me,

```
����: Failed to build the bibliography via bibtex
Please delete bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
ִֹͣ��

Exited with status 1.
```

Is there a solution?
There are some Chinese character in the title author and description, is this the reason?

The YAML header

```
--- 
title: "title"
author: "aa"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: ctexbook
bibliography: [book.bib]
biblio-style: nature
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
lot: no
lof: no
geometry: [b5paper, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm]
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
description: "dd。"
github-repo: yihui/bookdown-chinese
#cover-image: images/cover.jpg
---
```

Session:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     rstudioapi_0.7   xml2_1.2.0       knitr_1.20       magrittr_1.5     xtable_1.8-2    
 [7] R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.2.0      bibtex_0.4.2     plyr_1.8.4       httr_1.3.1       stringr_1.3.1   
[13] tools_3.5.0      xfun_0.1         miniUI_0.1.1     htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.1.19      assertthat_0.2.0
[19] rprojroot_1.3-2  digest_0.6.15    bookdown_0.7     RefManageR_1.2.0 later_0.7.2      promises_1.0.1  
[25] curl_3.2         evaluate_0.10.1  mime_0.5         rmarkdown_1.9    stringi_1.1.7    compiler_3.5.0  
[31] citr_0.2.0       backports_1.1.2  lubridate_1.7.4  jsonlite_1.5     httpuv_1.4.3
```

Comment: Your example does not contain any Chinese characters.  Does it compile? Are there any other error messages than the last one you quoted? Does your document compile if you do not change the bibliography style?  A [mcve] is most helpful in a case like this!

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689554/8416610

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner they can be compiled to pdf when I used apalike, and it would prompt error when I changed to nature.

Comment: Off the bat, I can see that `colorlinks` is indented. Beyond that, I prefer using [csl](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html) when using other citation style. I am not familiar with ctexbook but I was able to run your YAML after some [tweaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284881/chinese-ctex-tex-live-2015-on-ubuntu) in my manjaro machine.

Comment: I can also confirm that this runs with `pdflatex`. But then again the `.bib` file I am using doesn't have Chinese characters.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner it also prompted:The top-level auxiliary file: bookdown.aux
I couldn't open style file nature.bst
---line 18 of file bookdown.aux
 : \bibstyle{nature
 :                 }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file bookdown.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
����: Failed to build the bibliography via bibtex
Please delete bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
ִֹͣ��

Exited with status 1.

Comment: @ hpesoj626 sorry for the typo, the `colorlinks` is not indented.

Comment: the `-output.yml` showed it is `latex_engine: xelatex`

Comment: The additional error message indicates that you are missing the required bibliography style. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner, got it, thanks, how can I obtain the `nature.bst?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Download your .csl file from https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=nature
  and copy it to the root of your project.
- Set in _output.yml `citation_package: none`
- Add in all formats (gitbook, pdf_book,
  epub_book) in _output.yml the line `pandoc_args: [ "--csl",
  "your-csl-file.csl" ]`
- Delete or comment out in index.Rmd the line `biblio-style: apalike`

See for the full procedure [use csl-file for pdf-output in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown/49145699#49145699)

Answer (score 2):

You specify the bibtex style `nature.bst`, but that is not available on your system. Neither can I find it on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org). A search on CTAN gives two things:

- The [nature package](https://ctan.org/pkg/nature) which includes `naturemag.bst`
- The [biblatex-nature package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature) which adds nature like citations to biblatex

So either use

```
 biblio-style: naturemag
```

or (prefered, see below) switch to biblatex using

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  citation_package: biblatex
```

in `_output.yml`. In both cases you have to make sure that the required TeX packages are installed. This depends on the TeX distribution. In my case (TeXLive packaged for Debian) this meant

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers texlive-bibtex-extra
```

For TeXLive proper or TinyTeX you can use on the command line:

```
tlmgr install nature
tlmgr install biblatex-nature
```

For TinyTeX you can also do this within R:

```
library(tinytex)
tlmgr_install('nature')
tlmgr_install('biblatex-nature')
```

See the [maintenance section](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) for more details.

Unfortunately only the `bbilatex` solution is compatible with the default citation commands produced by `bookdown`. One probably could change insert LaTeX commands for the citations, but that would make producing other formats more complicated. In addition, `biblatex` is "the way to go" for many bibliography questions in LaTeX ...

Comment: I don't use Linux system but Windows

Comment: @MinyiHan And which TeX distribution do you use? MikTeX, TeXLive, TinyTeX, ...?

Comment: I installed the TinyTex

Comment: @MinyiHan Where you able to install (one of) the required TeX packages? Does it work now?

Comment: `library(tinytex)`
`tlmgr_install('nature')`
`tlmgr_install('biblatex-nature')` was used and  `biblio-style: naturemag` followed.  it prompted:   ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Error: Failed to compile bookdown.tex. See bookdown.log for more info.
Please delete bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

Comment: @MinyiHan I see. Try the `biblatex` solution then. That worked in my tests.